# Disabling hover event with the .not() method

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

I have the following code and I can't figure out why the `hoverIntent` event is firing although I assign the `selected-food` class to the `li` element on click.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7uPcc/2/

**Expected behaviour:** When a list item is clicked, the `selected-food` class is assigned to it (works fine) and the hidden div containing ingredients is not shown on hover. I'm trying to achieve this with the `.not()` method.

**Actual behaviour:** The hidden div is shown on hover although the hovered item has the `selected-food` class assigned.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="food-name">Food 1
        <div class="food-ingredients">
            <ul>
                <li>Ingredient 1</li>
                <li>Ingredient 2</li>
                <li>Ingredient 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>                    
    </li>
    <li class="food-name">Food 2
        <div class="food-ingredients">
            <ul>
                <li>Ingredient 1</li>
                <li>Ingredient 2</li>
                <li>Ingredient 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.food-ingredients {
    display: none;
}

.selected-food {
    color: red;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.food-name').not('.selected-food').hoverIntent({
    over: function() {
        $(this).children('.food-ingredients').show();
    }, 
    out: function() {
        $(this).children('.food-ingredients').hide();
    },
    timeout: 300
});

$('.food-name').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected-food');
});
```

When I test the `$('.food-name').not('.selected-food')` selector in the console I get the expected result (i.e. list items with the `selected-food` class are not returned)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hoverIntent event is bound to the elements on page load. At that time no elements have the class 'selected-food', so all of them trigger the hoverIntent event, even if you later add the 'selected-food' class to them.

Here is a working example:

```
$('.food-name').hoverIntent({
    over: function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('selected-food')) {
            $(this).children('.food-ingredients').show();
        }
    }, 
    out: function() {
        $(this).children('.food-ingredients').hide();
    },
    timeout: 300
});

$('.food-name').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected-food');
});
```

Link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7uPcc/8/

Comment: Thanks, a lot of great answers but this is the cleanest solution in my opinion and does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The event handler is being assigned before the class has been added.  Changing the class names later will have no effect on this.

This script will check to see if the class exists when the event fires...

```
$('.food-name').hoverIntent({
    over: function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("selected-food")) return;
        $(this).children('.food-ingredients').show();
    }, 
    out: function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("selected-food")) return;
        $(this).children('.food-ingredients').hide();
    },
    timeout: 300
});

$('.food-name').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected-food');
});
```

Here's an update to your fiddle example...

http://jsfiddle.net/7uPcc/11/

Comment: I see. I thought that the selector for the hoverIntent would be evaluated every time an item is hovered over. The code you have posted is not exactly what I'm trying to do because I still want to hide the div although the item has been clicked. But I will figure it out from here onwards. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use conditions in your functions:

```
    $('.food-name').hoverIntent({
        over: function() {
            if(!$(this).hasClass('selected-food')){
                $(this).children('.food-ingredients').show();
            }
        }, 
        out: function() {
            if(!$(this).hasClass('selected-food')){
                $(this).children('.food-ingredients').hide();
            }
        },
        timeout: 300
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$('.food-name').hoverIntent({
    over: function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('selected-food')) { 
          $(this).children('.food-ingredients').show();
        }
    }, 
    out: function() {
        $(this).children('.food-ingredients').hide();
    },
    timeout: 300
});

$('.food-name').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected-food').children('div')
           .toggle(!$(this).hasClass('selected-food'));
});
```

On hover over, only show the `food-ingredients` if the current item doesn't have the class `selected-food`.

In your click handler, toggle the visibility of the `food-ingredients` based on whether or not you've just added the `selected-food` class to it.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uPcc/13/)

Answer (score 0):

Because the event is bound to the set of matched elements at the time of running the code (`$('.food-name').not('.selected-food').hoverIntent`). When you remove the class, the element still got the trigger.

Add a if condition within your hover function or use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)